# IE TEXTAREA displays whitespace at end of line

Tags: internet-explorer, textarea, newline, whitespace

To get the bug, create a textarea with CSS text-align:right. Then, enter a line of text and create a newline. IE will put white space at the end of the line, but not in Chrome or any other browser.

Is there a solution to this bug with CSS or Javascript? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea style="white-space:pre"></textarea>`

Comment: Would be best not to make this inline, inline CSS is bad for structure.